# SSH connection, port 22: connection refused, when connected first to VPN server (PPTP)

Tags: ssh, vpn

I'm living in China and due to Great Chinese Firewall I need to use VPN to reach blocked web resources.
I'm experiencing **port 22: Connection timed out** when try co connect to my dev server via

```
ssh -A username@00.00.00.00
```

I can ping my server normally. And I can connect via SSH if I'm not using VPN.
Please, help me out.

-EDIT:

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with
SSH client configuration

```
Host        ga***st
User        i******ov
HostName    ***********ty.com
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

VPN client configuration (PPTP)

```
Authentication (enabled config): Use Point-to-Point encription (MPPE),
Allow DSB data compression, Allow default data compression,
Use TCP header compression, Send PPP echo pockets
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help you. There could be a myriad of reasons it's not working: SSH daemon configuration, SSH client configuration, VPN client configuration, VPN blocking, etc. Where you live and why you use VPN is irrelevant on the other hand. You need to troubleshoot and when you isolate the specific reason, ask about possible resolutions for the specific problem.

Comment: Maybe it's the authentication agent forwarding that's timing out. Does it work without the `-A`? (You'll have to authenticate differently of course)

Comment: @techraf Thank you for feedback, I added some information, please take look

Comment: @Spiff it doesn't work both with `-A` and without it